# Implementing http with zerotier sockets with c#

Tags: c#, http, sockets, signalr, zerotier

I am trying to use the httpclient with zerotier sockets and realise this might have to be done using a more custom approach however I also want to do the same but for signalr and I am not sure how to approach this, I know what I am doing isn't simple and likely going to require some custom code, but if anyone has any ideas of places I can look or things that already exist to help with this, that would be great.

I have seen okHttp and that might solve the httpclient problem, however I am not sure about the signalr.

Ideally I would Like to implement the sockets and add as little as possible to make this work, I know that is likely a lot more than i'm thinking but would really apprciate any resources people might have on this.